# Need to get the difference in milliseconds between two different timestamps using XQuery in MarkLogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-10

I need to add milliseconds into the timestamp and need to get the difference in milliseconds.

My Code:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $date1 := xs:dateTime("2022-01-17T21:45:00")
let $date2 := xs:dateTime("2022-01-17T22:45:00")
let $result := fn:abs(($date1 - $date2) div xs:dayTimeDuration("PT1S"))
return $result * 1000 (:Convert sec to ms:)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the duration presented in milliseconds, then divide by `xs:dayTimeDuration('PT0.001S')`

```
($date1 - $date2) div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT0.001S')
```

and if you want it as a positive number, then apply `abs()` as you were before:

```
abs(($date1 - $date2) div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT0.001S'))
```